# EXCEL replacing to new SKU

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

```
A1= 000AD21961PD
A2= 000BP20725PA
A3= 00C0BC23057C
A4= CS0321CS
```

How to make them to like this:-

```
C1= 000AD21961
C2= 000BP20725
C3= 00C0BC23057
C4= CS0321
```

I need to remove all alphabet in the end.

Comment: Can you at least tell us whether this data be in a row or a column?

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula in `C1` cell then drag and drop till your need.

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you found it working then you should accept (Tick it as green) my answer, so that other people can also know it is a useful answer.